# Entry Node exactly the same for days. 100 request to change and remains same

Tags: circuit, guard-node

I'm worried. I connect to exact same entry node for days.  Even after 100 new circuit requests, it hasn't moved.  Am I being watched? How can I get TOR to connect to different first node?